# How to aggregate data frame and keep missing values

Tags: r, null, aggregate

I have a data frame (data_test) of bird data where multiple counts of the same species can occur in the same location (ponds or transects). I would like to aggregate the data so there is one total count per species per location. I have missing values for the coordinates of some locations, but I don't want those records to be dropped out of the dataset. 
Here's the data:

```
# Create data table
location <- c("pondA","pondA","transect1","pondB","pondB","transect2","pondC","transect3","pondD","transect4")
type <- c("ground","ground","air","ground","ground","air","ground","air","ground","air")
easting <- c(NA,NA,18264,NA,NA,46378,NA,86025,NA,46295)
northing <-c(NA,NA,96022,NA,NA,85766,NA,21233,NA,23090)
species <- c("NOPI","NOPI","SCAU","GWTE","GWTE","RUDU","NOPI","GADW","NOPI","MALL")
count <- c(10,23,50,1,2,43,12,3,7,9)
data_test <- data.frame(location=location,type=type,easting=easting,northing=northing,species=species,count=count)
data_test
```

When I use the aggregate function, it drops out the records with missing easting and northing values:

```
aggregate(count ~ species + location + type + easting + northing, data=data_test, FUN=sum)
```

Results in:

```
  species  location type easting northing count
1    GADW transect3  air   86025    21233     3
2    MALL transect4  air   46295    23090     9
3    RUDU transect2  air   46378    85766    43
4    SCAU transect1  air   18264    96022    50
```

Using na.action=NULL doesn't work because the summation isn't operating on the easting or northing fields. What I want is:

```
  species  location   type easting northing count
1    NOPI     pondA ground      NA       NA    33
2    SCAU transect1    air   18264    96022    50
3    GWTE     pondB ground      NA       NA     3    
4    RUDU transect2    air   46378    85766    43
5    NOPI     pondC ground      NA       NA    12
6    GADW transect3    air   86025    21233     3
7    NOPI     pondD ground      NA       BA     7
8    MALL transect4    air   46295    23090     9
```

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One `data.table` route is to use the remaining names with `c()`

```
library(data.table)

dt <- as.data.table(data_test)
dt[, .(count = sum(count)), by = c(names(dt)[-6])]
#     location   type easting northing species count
# 1:     pondA ground      NA       NA    NOPI    33
# 2: transect1    air   18264    96022    SCAU    50
# 3:     pondB ground      NA       NA    GWTE     3
# 4: transect2    air   46378    85766    RUDU    43
# 5:     pondC ground      NA       NA    NOPI    12
# 6: transect3    air   86025    21233    GADW     3
# 7:     pondD ground      NA       NA    NOPI     7
# 8: transect4    air   46295    23090    MALL     9
```

Comment: Thanks, this works great! So the "-6" is a reference to the column that will be summed, correct?

Comment: @omwrichmond - Correct.  `[-6]` removes the 6th column from the names

Answer (score 2):

With `aggregate` one option would be to convert the grouping columns to 'factor' and adding "NA" as one of the levels with `addNA`

```
  nm1 <- setdiff(names(data_test), 'count')
  data_test[nm1] <- lapply(data_test[nm1], addNA)
  aggregate(count~., data_test, FUN=sum)
  #    location   type easting northing species count
  #1 transect3    air   86025    21233    GADW     3
  #2     pondB ground    <NA>     <NA>    GWTE     3
  #3 transect4    air   46295    23090    MALL     9
  #4     pondA ground    <NA>     <NA>    NOPI    33
  #5     pondC ground    <NA>     <NA>    NOPI    12
  #6     pondD ground    <NA>     <NA>    NOPI     7
  #7 transect2    air   46378    85766    RUDU    43
  #8 transect1    air   18264    96022    SCAU    50
```

Or using `dplyr`

```
 library(dplyr)
 data_test %>%
     group_by_(.dots=nm1) %>% 
     summarise(count=sum(count))
```

Comment: Nice thinking with the `addNA`

Comment: Thanks, the first one worked like a charm! But now each column is a factor--is there an easy was to get back the original types (character, date, numeric, etc)? Or would I need to use as.numeric, etc. on each column?

Comment: @omwrichmond  I was just showing a way with aggregate.  If you want to keep the original structure intact, dplyr or data.table solution is best.  Otherwise, you need to convert the columns back. i..e `if res <- aggregate(..., );; res[3:4] <- lapply(res[3:4], function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x)))`

Comment: OK thanks, yeah the data.table solution appears to be the easiest. The dplyr solution appears to have trouble with fields formatted as dates(?)

Comment: @omwrichmond  I thought your question is specific to aggregate.   Using your example, I didn't had such trouble.  But, it could be with dates.  Thanks for the feedback.